# Error loading data mat-select-list "values.forEach is not a function at MatSelectionList.push"

Tags: angular, angular-material

hello I have an error when trying to load data to a mat-select-list multiple those with the checkbox, from angular material, I have a rest service that loads me a combo with the mat-select-list and it works to insert information, but the problem is when I want to see the detail of that operation or edit it since I need to load the ones that were previously selected, the rest service that consumes the detail does not have the same structure with which I show the mat-select-list combo, it only has a field that is the code field and returns it as a string like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iyBf.png)

each value of those is supposed to be the identifier of the items of the combo array, so what I need is that those when loading appear selected.

```
documents: new FormControl(codigo)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXd9o.png)

my html code is as follows:

```
<mat-list-item>
                <mat-selection-list formControlName="documents" disabled multiple>
                  <mat-list-option   checkboxPosition="before" *ngFor="let document of setDocuments"
                                   [value]="document.codigoValor">
                    {{document.descripcion}}
                  </mat-list-option>
                </mat-selection-list>
              </mat-list-item>
```